# Data transfer through internet

Tags: c#, networking, data-transfer

I know this topic has been asked, i've used a lot of post from the internet like codeproject, stackoverflow, but i still can't transfer data between 2 computer not on LAN network.

Is it different between transfer on  LAN or through internet? Do i have to have a temp sever to do this task?

My program is working on LAN network but when i try to test program in WAN network, i setup the sever(receive) in my friend's computer that far from me, then, in my computer,in the client program,  i replaced the LAN's IP by the IP of my friend's computer, but it didn't work. Did i misunderstand anythings?

If you don't understand me, please give me link of solution or teach me how to transfer data between 2 not on LAN computer. Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English.

CODE: (only make the connection)

Receive: (i set up this on my friend's machine)

```
namespace RecieveFile
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
#region Variables
    private Thread thrDownload;
    private Stream strLocal;
    private NetworkStream strRemote;
    private TcpListener tlsServer;
    #endregion
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        thrDownload = new Thread(StartRecieving);
        thrDownload.Start();
   }
    public void StartRecieving()
    {
        try
        {
            string hstServer = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress ipaLocal = Dns.GetHostEntry(hstServer).AddressList[0];
            if (tlsServer == null)
            {
                tlsServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(29250));                

            }
            tlsServer.Start();

            TcpClient tclServer = tlsServer.AcceptTcpClient();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection has been created");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            strLocal.Close();
            strRemote.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("In finally");
            StartRecieving();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Send: (i set up this in my machine)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //171.255.9.234 is my friend's IP
     //if this ip is a ip of computer in my LAN network, it can work
        ConnectToSever("171.255.9.234", 29250);

    }
public void ConnectToSever(string severIP, int severPort)
    {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            tcpClient.Connect(severIP, severPort);
            MessageBox.Show("Connection has been created!","Message");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code otherwise this is just guesswork for us.

Comment: Assuming communication via TCP/IP, there isn't any difference from the perspective of application code.  With the information provided here, no one is really going to be able to tell you much, but regardless it's more of a question for Server Fault, although they may reject it too.

Comment: Thanks for your notice, i added code already, hope i could get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, without an actual code example, it's impossible to make specific statements.

That said, the usual reason that code works on a LAN but doesn't over the Internet is that the server end of the connection is behind a proxy, NAT router, or firewall.

You will have to ensure that if the server host has a firewall running, that the firewall settings are configured to allow network traffic through on the port(s) you expect. With the Windows firewall, by default Windows will display a prompt the first time you run an unauthorized program allowing you to grant access. Different firewall software on Windows, and of course, different firewalls on other operating systems, may or may not work similarly.

Likewise, if the server host uses a NAT router for Internet connectivity (common for residential and small-to-medium business Internet connections), the NAT router's "port forwarding" will need to be configured to deliver inbound traffic on a given port to the designated computer. A similar issue exists if there's a proxy server involved.

Also note that if a NAT router or proxy is involved, the IP address you need to configure as the server address in the client software is *not* the IP address of the actual machine being used to host the server process (which will be a LAN address), but rather the Internet-facing address that the NAT router or proxy server uses.

All of the above assumes IPv4. If you are using IPv6 (still not common on the Internet, but is supported end-to-end by some Internet providers), then the proxy and NAT issues should not be at issue, but a firewall still would be.

Comment: On the first time using the program, a window appear, i chose both of 2 option (i remember 1 allowed for LAN and 1  allowed for public), Was it the firewall configuration?
Someone recommend me about NAT, but i cant really understand what it is. Is NAT the solution? If it is, i will study about it. 
Thanks for your notice!

Comment: Yes, that was probably your firewall configuration. `NAT` is what a router uses (and probably your friend's router) to share a single Internet connection between multiple computers (or other devices). `NAT` isn't a solution to _your_ problem; it's probably what's _causing_ your problem (but it's a solution to other problems, so your solution isn't to get rid of it...your solution is to configure the NAT router correctly).

Comment: Can i configure the NAT router by coding in C#? I would like to programing a program similar to Teamviewer. I found Teamviewer has the service "Call over IP" and Copy/Paste between two machine easily, does it have any temp server or virtual machine to do this task? I thought it's not,because it's free, that's why i learnt about socket, TCP/IP method but i couldn't find the solution :(

Comment: I don't know anything about "Teamviewer" (whatever that is). Most NAT routers can be configured programmatically via "Universal Plug-and-Play". But that would just be complicating things for you at the moment, I believe. You should be familiar with the concept of port forwarding and how to manually configure at least one router first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm gonna explore more about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to set up some `Port Forwarding` in both of your routers for the port(s) that your program is using to communicate to make it work over WAN. In a LAN it's easier since it's usually open for all ports as a default.

How to set up Port Forwarding depends on your routers but some information can be found at [http://portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/)